# In Javascript, how do I create data- attributes inside options from an object?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a project for a while in my spare time. I am currently trying to store data for later use.

```
let weapons = [
{
  type: "Revolver",
  bMats: 60,
  cTime: 50,
},
{
  type: "Rifle",
  bMats: 100,
  cTime: 70,
},
{
  type: "Shotgun",
  bMats: 120,
  cTime: 80,
}
];
```

This is a small sample of all the objects in the array.I used the following code to create the options:

```
let wSelect = document.getElementById('wpsl1');
wSelect.appendChild(new Option(weapons[i].type));
```

There are 4 selects in this area, so I just changed the id of each select. The part I cannot figure out is how to assign each bMats and cTime property to each option using a loop. The end result should look like this:

```
<select id="wpsl1">
     <option>--SELECT ONE--</option>
     <option data-mats= "60" data-time="50">Revolver</option>
     <option data-mats= "100" data-time="70">Rifle</option>
     <option data-mats= "120" data-time="80">Shotgun</option>
</select>
<select id="wpsl2">
     <option>--SELECT ONE--</option>
     <option data-mats= "60" data-time="50">Revolver</option>
     <option data-mats= "100" data-time="70">Rifle</option>
     <option data-mats= "120" data-time="80">Shotgun</option>
</select>
<select id="wpsl3">
     <option>--SELECT ONE--</option>
     <option data-mats= "60" data-time="50">Revolver</option>
     <option data-mats= "100" data-time="70">Rifle</option>
     <option data-mats= "120" data-time="80">Shotgun</option>
</select>
<select id="wpsl4">
     <option>--SELECT ONE--</option>
     <option data-mats="60" data-time="50">Revolver</option>
     <option data-mats="100" data-time="70">Rifle</option>
     <option data-mats="120" data-time="80">Shotgun</option>
</select>
```

If you prefer, here is a jsFiddle instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/wm5z9s7r/15/

Any information on how to proceed is appreciated. I scoured the site for weeks looking for a solution. I do tend to get roasted when I ask questions, so I was extra viligant this time.

Comment: an elements `data-*` attributes can be accessed using `element.dataset`

Comment: I'm not accessing them. I'm trying to create them.

Comment: You create them the same way, through the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Syntax)

Comment: by `access` I mean get or set

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, I looked at that, but that is how you do it for each option. I am trying to assign the object properties to the select options with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not modifying the `option` elements after its creation, you are just adding the text in the `option` at creation time:

```
wSelect.appendChild(new Option(weapons[i].type));
```

A better way to do this is using the your array to populate each select in its own loop execution, that way you can create a single `option` element, set the data, the value, the text, and append it to the `select`.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  const select = document.getElementById('wpsl' + i)

  weapons.forEach(function(weapon) {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.dataset.mats = weapon.bMats
    option.dataset.time = weapon.cTime
    option.value = weapon.type
    option.text = weapon.type
    select.appendChild(option)
  })
}
```

The problem I see with this approach is that you won't be able to add or remove `select`s in the future without changing the second parameter in the `for` loop, so I would recommend to use classes to the html selector to get the possible number of `select`s in the page, then use that array add the `option`s to each `select`.

```
<select id="wpsl1" class="weapon-select"> ... </select> // HTML element

const select = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.weapon-select'))

select.forEach(function(select) {
  weapons.forEach(function(weapon) {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.dataset.mats = weapon.bMats
    option.dataset.time = weapon.cTime
    option.value = weapon.type
    option.text = weapon.type
    select.appendChild(option)
  })
})
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the reply. I was trying to modify data that didn't exist. How does the engine know that you are referencing the weapons array when you use weapon instead in the parameter? I could probably make my solution work, now, but yours is much more concise.

Comment: Is there any advantage to access by querySelectorAll over id?

Comment: The `id`s are unique, so there's no good way to match all the `id`s and get the array you expect without creation a weird loop to get any individual select and fill an array for later use.

Use `id`s for other purposes like matching a single element for an specific reason.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why array.prototype.slice.call() was used here?

Comment: -- Now that most browsers have implemented querySelectorAll, the native selectorEngine, many framework-dependent developers are getting a rude awakening when dealing with the result of QSA calls:  the NodeList object.  NodeLists are array-like but don't feature many of the methods provided by the Array, like forEach, map, filter, etc. --

https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array